# active storage / clean files url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, cloud, rails-activestorage

Multiple question around the same issue, the way active storage returns file urls

For now with the default setup, the following (cloud or local), returns somehow the following :

`_domain/_path/_superlong_hash/_original_filename._ext`

Given paperclip or many other existing gems, the _path/_superlong_hash/_original_filename._ext part is in hand to be customised, could end up in a clean url for any files

Meaning by that :

- is there a way to "proxy" the `_path` with something more custom ?
- is there a way to avoid the `_superlong_hash` ?
- is there a way to customize the  filename on the fly (or on uploads) ?

To make it a one-liner, how one would customize the files urls ?

I've seen here and there people ending up creating custom controllers to serve file with decent urls, but let's admit this is  a no go (IMHO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that ActiveStorage proves me wrong soon, but at the time of writing Rails 5.2, the straight answer seems to be that you have to go with your 'no go' option, hacking your own controllers together and heavily patching ActiveStorage to expose files.

**For proxying see:**

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31419

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30465

- especially georgeclaghorn responses are interesting

**For renaming file:**

```
@user.avatar.blob.update(filename: 'NewFilename.jpg')
```

**Manipulating the _superlong_hash / url**

I have no good answer for this one. Although ActiveStorage makes it breathtakingly easy to upload (and somewhat easy to manipulate) files it takes Rails opinionated software philosophy to the edge, making it quite difficult to bypass it's obscurity by abstraction approach to url generation. ActiveStorage provides no built-in methods to do rudimentary things like permanent or direct links to files and variants once generated. File/image caching and nice urls seem therefore not to be possible to accomplish out of the box with ActiveStorage at this point in time.

Comment: On the IMHO side of things, I would like to add that I don't think ActiveStorage currently is recommendable to anyone but developers who have applications that very accurately match the behaviour of Basecamp. Also the route hi-jacking of ActiveStorage is a major concern/bug https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31228

For everyone else CarrierWave is a more sensible and configurable option.

Comment: Was into the same opinion, but based on the fact that more and more people are going to use proxies services (cloudinary, imgix, etc... or any other equivalent), the thing could start to make sense for the upload part *ONLY*. Which does not makes it a perfect solution, we can all agree that active storage is missing something somehow if it has to cover every requirements